# Does adding an internal ID to database table improve performance?

Tags: database

currently i have a unique business key which is set as primary key to identify the table records.

recently my team suggested to add one more internal autonumber id which they feedback will improve performance.

Is this really the case and should i really create the additional internal autonumber id even through i already have a unique business key to improve the performance

Comment: improve performance of _what_ exactly? If you are just going to add another extra key; it may do the opposite and end up reducing your preformance; especially if you are doing a lot of writes to the table.

Comment: Performance of insertion decrease with the number of index to update. Performance of selection increase with the number of index on the joining columns... I agree with Burhan, adding a redundant index don't help

Comment: Q: Will adding a second, useless key improve performance?  A: Uh, why *should* it?  No.  At best, it could *decrease* performance.  Especially if you index it :)